# CSS file showing as "text/x-csrc", being read as text/html in browser and ignored

Tags: css, mime-types

Several css files included in a Traq installation package are showing a MIME type of "text/x-csrc" on the server.  The files are being read as text/html by the browser and are ignored.

CSS files for other virtualhosted sites appear as text/css.

[image]

I've tried copying and pasting contents of the "text/x-csrc" file into a text editor, then creating a new file on the server and pasting with vi.   Same result.

Here is the suspect file, [install.css](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g2f70e399152b7a74155102f8b62e2acf688c57):

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*!
 * Traq Install
 * Copyright (c) 2009-2012 Traq.io
 * @license GNU General Public License v3 only
 */
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #e9e9e9;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 30px; }

#wrapper {
    width: 580px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); }

header {
    background: #3478AA;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; }
header h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left; }
header h2 {
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold; }

#page {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: -5px 0;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px; }

code {
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}

#licence, #config_code {
    width: 550px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: scroll;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #F6F6F6;
    border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace; }
#config_code {
    height: 125px }

.tabular .group {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    padding-left: 250px;
    clear: left; }
.tabular label {
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -250px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 245px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 3px; }
.tabular input {
    margin-top: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle; }
.tabular select {
    margin-top: 0; }

.actions {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px; }

.error label {
    color: red; }
.error input {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 2px; }

footer {
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 6px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px; }
```

What in this file could be triggering an incorrect MIME type?

**EDIT:**

The first two characters in install.css were `/*` - opening tag of a comment.  Apparently my Apache magic file interpreted this as "C Source" instead of CSS.

Adding a line return to the beginning of the default install.css file changed the MIME type from C Source to CSS.

The file is still being incorrectly identified as text/html by Chrome/Firefox.  I've added this to httpd.conf:

```
AddType text/css .css
```

Still no dice.  Both Firefox and Chrome are incorrectly reading this as text/html.

Help?

Comment: The web browser would rely on the `Content-Type` set by the server to determine the type. You would need to check what value is being returned in the response, and the configuration for it.

Answer (score -1):

Your reading this from a external database or something? I guess you missed the tags to open and close style.

Comment: It's the file included in the Traq installer.  It is included with <style> @import url("/trac/install/install.css"); </style>

Comment: Additionally, the other file (nbs.css), is included in the same manner.  There is just text in both files.   Opening/closing tags are not required in included stylesheets.

Comment: I didnt know it was with tags on the import, no need to downvote.

Comment: The answer makes it appear that style tags are required with .css files (which are by nature, included).   I'll give you some slack but I've had answers downvoted for lesser interpretations.  Nobody cut me slack.

Comment: It says I can't undo the downvote.. maybe that's why nobody cut me slack, they couldn't!   Don't take offense, it's not personal!